# Why is there no cite option on Cross Validated?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, references

I just found that on the [Physics Stack Exchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) they have the option to [cite](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7056/what-is-the-function-of-cite-below-each-question-answer) answers and questions:

[image: cite]

As mentioned in [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189213/add-the-ability-to-cite-questions-and-answers), this option is also available for example on the [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/) and [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange sites. There is no clear answer to [a meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189213/add-the-ability-to-cite-questions-and-answers) regarding why this option is not globally available on all StackExchange sites, but the comments are slightly negative. I agree that in most cases it is not a good idea to use this in scientific articles, as also [discussed here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2051/can-i-cite-a-question-response-to-an-academic-paper).
However, when for example writing a (technical) report, this option might be useful. Moreover, the option already seems to exist on the StackExchange network.

Comment: I heard an opinion (from somebody doing research on sociology of science) that physics is one of few disciplines with a high degree of internal consensus. If you show a paper about a perpetuum mobile to five physicists, they would all agree it's BS. If you show a paper with an OLS regression to a frequentist statistician, to a Bayesian statistician, to an econometrician, to a machine learning researcher, you will probably get four different answers. So it's more acceptable in physics to use one person's post as it is relatively likely to be representative of what the discipline thinks.

Comment: [ctd] Also, physicists are quite used to referencing online resources, primarily arXiv. (It's kinda there for statistics, too, but I don't know how much it is being used; theoretical/mathematical statisticians do post there a lot, but my own area, survey statistics, is very poorly represented.) Note finally that there aren't that very many people who use real names on CV, so while material by say whuber is always of high rigor, you would have to edit that BibTeX snippet to put his name in (which he may not really want that much, as a matter of fact).

Comment: Does anyone know of a downside?

Comment: @AndreSilva Well, I think that one question should actually be merged with this one, which is older

Comment: @Firebug, It is not mandatory that the older question remains as the original one, though it could be merged (but I don't think it is necessary, bacause merge is for when there are very useful answers in both posts).

Comment: @AndreSilva Yeah, you're right in that regard, what I meant is that we should have actually perceived the duplication before. Now I deleted my asnwer and the one you linked is the canonical answer, so we should really merge this one question into the one you linked.