# Incorrect number of badges?

Tags: discussion, badges

In the top bar of this Cross Validated Meta site, I see that I have one gold, six silver, and five bronze badges. In my profile pages, however, I see one gold (fanatic), one silver (enthusiast), and six bronze badges (Autobiographer, Critic, Student, Suffrage, Supporter, Vox populi).

Why is there such a discrepancy?
1, 6, 5 vs. 1, 1, 6

Comment: I think I solved one of the problems. There are five 'yearling' badges. But I still wonder one missing bronze badge.

Comment: Meta and main badge counts are separate. Does that help resolve the difference?

Comment: @mkt No. I know that.

Comment: Can you add screenshots? Your flair underneath your question shows 1/6/7 badges, and this corresponds to what I see on your Meta profile page (Fanatic; 5x Yearling, Enthusiastic; Vox Populi, Suffrage, Critic, Supporter, Autobiographer, Nice Question, Student). So no problem I can see. Are you sure you don't have Nice Question? It should have been awarded on May 11, 2014 for [this](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2051/can-i-cite-a-question-response-to-an-academic-paper).

Comment: @StephanKolassa The problem has been solved now. I think it took some time that the new badge I got is shown to the upper bar.